# Footnote on each page

Tags: footnotes

I have a table over two pages and some values with the same footnote. I need the footnote on both pages (under the tabel). How can I do this?
Thanks in advance,
Isabell

```
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}
\tablecaption{My table with problems}
 \tablehead{\hline\centering Atom&\parbox[t][0.3cm]{1.576cm}{\vspace*{\fill}\centering  $W_\text{i}$ in eV} &\vspace*{\fill} Referenz &
 \parbox[t][0.3cm]{3.19cm}{\vspace*{\fill}\centering  $W_\text{ea}$ in eV}&\vspace*{\fill} Referenz &  
 \parbox[t][0.95cm]{2cm}{\centering  Value A} & \vspace*{\fill}   Referenz\\ \hline\hline}
\tabletail{\hline}

\begin{mpsupertabular}{|p{1.532 cm}||S[table-number-alignment = center,table-figures-integer = 2,table-figures-decimal = 2]|p{1.532 cm}"S[table-number-alignment = center,table-figures-integer = 1,table-figures-decimal = 2,table-comparator = true,table-align-comparator = false,retain-explicit-plus,input-uncertainty-signs,separate-uncertainty  = true, uncertainty-separator =  {\,}, table-space-text-pre = ~\,,table-space-text-post = \,~~~~]|p{1.532 cm}"S[table-number-alignment = center,table-figures-integer = 1,table-figures-decimal = 2]|p{1.532 cm}|}

\ce{S}& 10,4 &\cite{Fis-07} &-2,077&\cite{Hay-13}&2,5&\cite{Fas-05}\\ 
 &10,51\text{\footnote{Text I need on both pages \label{fn:TEXT}}} & &&&&\\ \hline
 %lots of other values
 \end{mpsupertabular}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?